# Difference between 'hac-groupsum' and `hac-panel’ for statsmodels robust covariance

Tags: data-analysis, statsmodels

I'm looking at the `cov_type` for robust covariance estimation in statsmodels by `statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.get_robustcov_results`, and it looks to me both `hac-groupsum` and `hac-panel` can both be applied to panel data for robust covariance estimation, what is the difference between those two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.get_robustcov_results.html

`hac-groupsum` is

> Driscoll and Kraay, heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation robust covariance for panel data

While `hac-panel` is

> heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation robust standard errors in panel data. The data needs to be sorted in this case, the time series for each panel unit or cluster need to be stacked. The membership to a time series of an individual or group can be either specified by group indicators or by increasing time periods. One of groups or time is required.

`hac-panel` has defined groups also while `hac-groupsum` doesn't have that input.

The code for this is found here from lines 293 - 344. https://coveralls.io/builds/26080820/source?filename=statsmodels%2Fbase%2Fcovtype.py

Comment: Since only one of groups or time is required for hac-panel, suppose I use time for both hac-panel and hac-groupsum, should I expect they work the same way?

Comment: See code in edited response.